# Issues with React Router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I have an issue with **react-router-dom v6**.
Firstly, I defined the routes in a single file like this (well, It is cloned from somewhere and I am trying to adapt it to my needs):

```
// routes.tsx

import Dashboard from "../views/Dashboard";
import Notifications from "../views/Notifications";
import Icons from "../views/Icons";
import TableList from "../views/Tables";
import Maps from "../views/Map";
import UserPage from "../views/User";
import React from "react";
import Register from "../views/Register";
import Login from "../views/Login";
import Accounts from "../views/Accounts";

var routes = [
  {
    pro: false,
    path: "/register",
    name: "Register",
    icon: "nc-icon nc-chart-pie-36",
    component: <Register />,
    layout: "/guest",
    private: false
  },
  {
    pro: false,
    path: "/",
    name: "Login",
    icon: "nc-icon nc-chart-pie-36",
    component: <Login />,
    layout: "/guest",
    private: false
  },
  {
    pro: false,
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "Dashboard",
    icon: "nc-icon nc-chart-pie-36",
    component: <Dashboard />,
    layout: "/admin",
    private: true
  },
  {
    pro: false,
    path: "/accounts",
    name: "Accounts",
    icon: "nc-icon nc-bank",
    component: <Accounts />,
    layout: "/admin",
    private: true
  },
  {
    pro: false,
    path: "/icons",
    name: "Companies",
    icon: "nc-icon nc-bank",
    component: <Icons />,
    layout: "/admin",
    private: true
  },
  {
    pro: false,
    path: "/maps",
    name: "Admins",
    icon: "nc-icon nc-single-02",
    component: <Maps />,
    layout: "/admin",
    private: true
  },
  {
    pro: false,
    path: "/notifications",
    name: "Notifications",
    icon: "nc-icon nc-bell-55",
    component: <Notifications />,
    layout: "/admin",
    private: true
  },
  {
    pro: false,
    path: "/user-page",
    name: "Settings",
    icon: "nc-icon nc-settings-gear-65",
    component: <UserPage />,
    layout: "/admin",
    private: true
  },
  {
    pro: false,
    path: "/tables",
    name: "Work Orders",
    icon: "nc-icon nc-single-copy-04",
    component: <TableList />,
    layout: "/admin",
  },
];
export default routes;
```

As you can see, There are layout routes: `'/admin/*'` and `'/guest/*'`.
Now there are Layout components where the routes are called and mapped, This is the code of **AdminLayout.tsx** for example:

```
// AdminLayout.tsx
import React from "react";

// javascript plugin used to create scrollbars on windows
import PerfectScrollbar from "perfect-scrollbar";

import { Route, Routes, useLocation, RouteProps } from "react-router-dom";

import DemoNavbar from "../components/Navbars/DemoNavbar";
import Sidebar from "../components/Sidebar/Sidebar";

import routes from "../utils/routes";

var ps: any;

function AdminLayout(props: any) {
  const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = React.useState("black");
  const [activeColor, setActiveColor] = React.useState("info");
  const mainPanel = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const location = useLocation();
  const sidebar = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Win") > -1 && sidebar.current) {
      ps = new PerfectScrollbar(sidebar.current, {
        suppressScrollX: true,
        suppressScrollY: false,
      });
    }

    return function cleanup() {
      if (ps) {
        ps.destroy();
        ps = null;
      }
    };
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (mainPanel.current) {
      mainPanel.current.scrollTop = 0;
    }
    if (document.scrollingElement) {
      document.scrollingElement.scrollTop = 0;
    }
  }, [location]);
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <Sidebar
        {...props}
        routes={routes.filter((route) => route.private == true)}
        bgColor={backgroundColor}
        activeColor={activeColor}
      />
      <div
        className="main-panel"
        //ref={mainPanel}
      >
        <DemoNavbar {...props} />
        <Routes>
          {routes.map((prop, key) => {
            return (
              <Route
                path={prop.path}
                element={prop.component}
                key={key}
                caseSensitive
              />
            );
          })}
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AdminLayout;
```

The routes are also called and mapped in **Sidebar.tsx**:

```
// Sidebar.tsx
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { NavLink, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { Nav } from "reactstrap";
import PerfectScrollbar from "perfect-scrollbar";

//import logo from "../../logo.svg";
import logo from "../../assets/img/logo-no-background.png"

let ps: PerfectScrollbar | null = null;

interface RouteProps {
  pro: boolean
  path: string 
  icon: string 
  layout: string 
  name: string
  private: boolean
}

interface SidebarProps {
  bgColor: string
  activeColor: string
  routes: RouteProps[]
}

const Sidebar: React.FC<SidebarProps> = (props: SidebarProps) => {
  const { bgColor, activeColor, routes } = props

  const location = useLocation();
  const sidebar = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  // verifies if routeName is the one active (in browser input)
  const activeRoute = (routeName: string): string => {
    return location.pathname.startsWith(routeName) ? "active" : "";
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (navigator.platform.includes("Win") && sidebar.current) {
      ps = new PerfectScrollbar(sidebar.current, {
        suppressScrollX: true,
        suppressScrollY: false,
      });
    }

    return function cleanup() {
      if (ps) {
        ps.destroy();
        ps = null;
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      className="sidebar"
      data-color={bgColor}
      data-active-color={activeColor}
    >
      <div className="logo" style={{ padding: '10% 10% 15%' }}>
        <a
          href="/"
          className="simple-text logo-normal"
        >
          <img src={logo} alt="af-logo" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div className="sidebar-wrapper" 
      ref={sidebar}
      >
        <Nav>
          {routes.map((prop: RouteProps, key: number) => {
            return (
              <li
                className={
                  activeRoute(prop.path) + (prop.pro ? " active-pro" : "")
                }
                key={key}
              >
                <NavLink to={prop.layout + prop.path} className="nav-link">
                  <i className={prop.icon} />
                  <p className="text-capitalize">{prop.name}</p>
                </NavLink>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </Nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Now, the issue is when I click to any of this navlinks in the side bar, I am redirected to its appropriate route except for accounts, I am redirected to `localhost:3000/admin/accounts` for few milliseconds then I am redirected automatically to `localhost:3000/guest`.

**Note:** I am using PrivateRoute to wrap the AdminLayout as the dashboard must be accessed only if the user is authenticated. The code of **PrivateRoute.tsx** component:

```
// PrivateRoute.tsx

import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

interface PrivateRouteProps {
  children: any
}

const PrivateRoute: React.FC<PrivateRouteProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector((state: any) => state.auth.isAuthenticated);
  
  return isAuthenticated ? (
    <>{children}</>
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/guest/login" replace />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

And this is I am using the components in **App.tsx**:

```
// App.tsx

import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Route,
  Routes,
  useLocation,
  useNavigate,
  redirect
} from "react-router-dom";

import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css"; // import first
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";

import AdminLayout from "./layouts/Admin";
import GuestLayout from "./layouts/Guest";
import setToken from "./utils/setAuthToken";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getAuthenticatedUser } from "./redux/slices/auth.slice";
import PrivateRoute from "./layouts/PrivateRoute";
import Loader from "./layouts/Loader";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const location = useLocation()
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  // Check if user is authenticated and set the token
  if (localStorage.token) {
    setToken(localStorage.token);
  }

  // Dispatch getAuthenticatedUser action
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAuthenticatedUser());
  }, [dispatch]);

  // Get the authentication state from Redux store
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector(
    (state: any) => state.auth.isAuthenticated
  );

  const isLoading = useSelector(
    (state: any) => state.auth.isLoading
  );

   useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoading) {
      return; 
    }

    if (isAuthenticated) {
      navigate("/admin/dashboard");
    } else {
      navigate("/guest");
    }

  }, [isAuthenticated, isLoading]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <Loader />
    )
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <ToastContainer />
      <>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/admin/*"
            element={
              <PrivateRoute>
                <AdminLayout />
              </PrivateRoute>
            }
          />
          <Route path="/guest/*" element={<GuestLayout />} />
        </Routes>
      </>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And Finally, This is the code of **Accounts.tsx**:

```
// Accounts.tsx

import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

// reactstrap components
import { Card, CardHeader, CardBody, CardTitle, Row, Col } from "reactstrap";
import { getAccountList } from "../redux/slices/account.slice";

const Accounts: React.FC = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("got the account list")
    dispatch(getAccountList());
  }, []);

  const accountList = useSelector(
    (state: any) => state.account?.accountList?.accountList
  );
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="content">
        <Row>
          <Col md="12">
            <Card className="demo-icons">
              <CardHeader>
                <CardTitle tag="h5">100 Awesome Nucleo Icons </CardTitle>
                <p className="card-category">
                  Handcrafted by our friends from{" "}
                  <a href="https://nucleoapp.com/?ref=1712">NucleoApp</a>
                </p>
              </CardHeader>
              <CardBody className="all-icons">
                <div id="icons-wrapper">
                  <section>
                    <ul>
                      {accountList && accountList?.map((account: any) => (
                        <li key={account?._id}>
                          <i className="nc-icon nc-air-baloon" />
                          <p>{account?.accountType}</p>
                          <em>{account?.feesPerPersonPerMonth}</em>
                        </li>
                      ))}

                      <li>
                        <i className="nc-icon nc-simple-add" />
                        <p>Add New Account Category</p>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </section>
                </div>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Accounts;
```

Can anyone help me ? I am stuck and I could not spot the cause of the issue so I provided a plenty of code. Can you help explain to me what causes the problem and how to fix it ?

Comment: Have you checked your authenticated status on accounts page? Not so sure if this is the root cause but if your `getAccountList` has updated the isLoading state. Then this also trigger a re-run of useEffect in App.tsx to navigate to guest if user is not authenticated.

Comment: Yes ! I checked it, isAuthenticated is true on accounts page and the  local storage contains the token.
dispatch(getAccountList()) triggers the problem (I tried to comment it, and the issue is gone), but how to solve the problem as I want to get the account list before rendering the page ?

Comment: That's strange, you could start investigating your authenticating mechanism Raj. There could be the case where the authenticator try to authenticate again which unexpectedly change isAuthenticated to false while re-authenticating

Comment: I provided you the whole code of accountSlice in the answers, can you help me if there are any issues ? I get the the list of accounts correctly, the problem is only in the navigation

Comment: You shouldn't put it in the answer, Boudagga. It's not the place to provide info. Btw, It's better to set debugger with your auth slice (accounts slice has nothing to do with the routing as I can see)

Comment: This looks like a bit of a code dump. What exactly is the issue you want help with here? Is this ***really*** the minimal amount of code necessary to reproduce the issue you face? See [mcve].